# SASS: BEM --pink to a P element

Tags: html, sass, bem

I've delcared my modifier to the P element as per below. In HTML (at the bottom), what am I doing incorrectly as the p tags do not change to pink if I declare the class name as shown.

```
p {
    font-size: 1rem;

    &--pink{
        color: pink;
    }
}
```

```
  <p class="block__p --pink">this is placeholder text.</p>
```

I thought it was a simple spacing error from the p to the " --pink" but that makes no difference to the outcome.

```
  <p class="block__p--pink">this is placeholder text.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct selector for a `<p>` tag with a class of `--pink` is `p.--pink`. You are missing the `.` ([class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)).

```scss
p {
  font-size: 1rem;

  &.--pink{
    color: pink;
  }
}
```

[See it working](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/n4k8mL2r/).

I recommend [The Sass Playground](https://www.sassmeister.com/), which allows you to see in real time the CSS output of your SCSS.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. This has solved it. Thank you for also recommending the Sass playground, I will be using this moving forward!